# Unable to add links or images in rss feed in <item> tag

Tags: php, mysql, xml, tags, rss

I would appreciate some help. I am trying to create RSS feed for my website. I got half of it working, but I just want help with other half. I can't seem to add link to titles and I can't seem to be able to display a thumbnail in  tag. Can someone help me please?

This is my code so far:

```
 <?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');   
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');   
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');   
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'testdb'); 

$connection = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)
    or die('Could not connect to database');
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)
    or die ('Could not select database');


$query = "SELECT teste.id, teste.title, teste.abstract, teste.body, teste.keywords, tesi.image FROM teste INNER JOIN tesi ON teste.title = tesi.title WHERE teste.title = tesi.title";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not execute query");


$data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
$data .= '<rss version="2.0">';
$data .= '<channel>';
$data .= '<title>Bang Premier</title>';
$data .= '<link>http://www.bangpremier.com</link>';
$data .= '<description>Entertainment News</description>';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);
$data .= '<item>';
$data .= '<title>'.$row['title'].'</title>';
$data .= '<link>'.$row['image'].'</link>';
$data .= '<description>'.$row['abstract'].'</description>';
$data .= '</item>';
}
$data .= '</channel>';
$data .= '</rss> ';

header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Either image & link doesn't show at all or either, all the data disappears, only channel name and channel description appears. (No specific error). It just doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

To debug the error look at the generated XML. For example open the source view in the browser. You should see something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Bang Premier</title>
    <link>http://www.bangpremier.com</link>
    <description>Entertainment News</description>
    <item>
      <title>Some Title</title>
      <link>http://some.domain.tld/link</link>
      <description>Some content</description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Validate that the feed is valid wellformed XML and contains the data. The code in your question inserts the `image` database field as link.

For this you should escape the values from the database using `htmlspecialchars()` or even better use an XML Api like DOM or XMLWriter to generate the output.

[RSS 2.0 feed items](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt) do not have an `image` element - only the `channel`.

You can include it as an `img` element inside the `description`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <item>
      <title>Some Title</title>
      <link>http://some.domain.tld/link</link>
      <description>
        &lt;img src="http:/example.tld/images/thumbnail.png">
        &lt;br>
        Some content
      </description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Some clients will edit the HTML however and may strip the `img`.

Depending on your feed and the expected clients [Media-RSS](http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss#media-group) could be an option, too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I am trying to work on what you said. Do you have any way how to add link to the title (using php), i am trying but it's not working. This is my code: 

 $data .= '<title>'.'<a href="http://website.com/preem.php?id="'. $row['id'].'"\">'.$row['title'].'</a>'.'</title>';

Comment: No the contents of the `title` element is text. But if you put a valid url into the `link` element the RSS client should read it.